# Как написать такую библиотеку чтобы можно было запустить файл на определенное время

Tags: c#, framework, asp, core

подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли запустить файл `.exe/.dll` на определенное время(`timeout`)?

Компиляция файла:
`c# asp.net framework/core`

```cs
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new string[]
{
    "mscorlib.dll",
    "System.Core.dll"
}, "имя_файла.(exe/dll)", true);
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;

var file = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSourse(parameters, "код");
```

Важно: файл должен быть управляемым процессом, для того чтобы после окончания `timeout` `c#` просто завершил(рашнул) выполнение файла.

Comment: [Task.Delay(timeout)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-5.0) + Process.Kill.